# os-prober not finding windows on intel softraid

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, raid, mdadm, os-prober

### Background:

I have a Desktop with the following drive configuration:

- Ubuntu 20.04 on single SSD
- Windows 10 on a Intel RST Raid across 2 SSDs

OS's are installed in UEFI mode

### Problem:

OS prober does not find the windows installation on the Intel RST Raid despite being able to mount the partition with the EFI files. It finds the Ubuntu EFI files fine. Upon further investigation of why I stumbled across lines 31-35 of `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi` and the debug line there showing up in the logs. Upon running the udevadm command in the condititional it spits out.

```
 /devices/virtual/block/md126/md126p1
```

Which means it won't look for EFI files on this partition because it is a virtual disk.

### Workaround

Open `/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/05efi` in vim and comment out line 34. This allows os-prober to correctly find the Windows EFI files and populate the menus in grub correctly, the machine can now boot windows and ubuntu from grub successfully.

#### Question

I know that all code is written for a reason and this was put here at some point. I am curious:

1. Is there a reason I shouldn't just comment this out (or make it smarter by checking for 'md' in the path with grep)?
2. Is it possible if I have something set up wrong in mdadm and that's why it shows up as a virtual device? My mdadm conf is as follows:

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# !NB! Run update-initramfs -u after updating this file.
# !NB! This will ensure that initramfs has an uptodate copy.
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY metadata=imsm UUID=ef7f02c0:f0d35b35:760ba725:f4c93763
ARRAY /dev/md/SSDRaid container=ef7f02c0:f0d35b35:760ba725:f4c93763 member=0 UUID=d3be1bc0:8dd0f96d:f53e5af5:4974fe26

# This configuration was auto-generated on Sat, 01 May 2021 20:33:32 -0500 by mkconf
```

Comment: Intel RST RAID is not supported in Linux operating systems.  It's a proprietary "RAID" that does not really function in Linux environments.  Running in Intel RST "RAID" is not supported on Linux.

Comment: I understand that, and that's why my Linux installation is not on the raid but on its own SSD (which now that I've looked is even on a different SATA controller). However, Windows does which is why I felt comfortable putting it on the raid drives.

Comment: perhaps I wasn't clear - all components of Linux, GRUB included which os-prober populates - don't work with Intel RST.  Different SATA controller or not, the Intel RAID format is **simply not supported on Linux** and that's why your Windows partitions and install on the RAID isn't found - Linux and osprober have no support for the RST format of RAID.

Comment: It is found though if I simply comment out line 34 of /usr/lib/os-probes/05efi and grub does find and boot the efi files off it. mdadm can assemble an intel soft raid since it seems at least 2011 ( according to this whitepaper they contributed to the code to make it able to do so https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/white-papers/rst-linux-paper.pdf ). I understand that it isn't supported, but it does work.

Answer (score 0):

I too ran into this issue on my laptop.  I have an MSI GT60 and it comes with 1 SSD and 1 HDD from the factory, however it has 3 MSATA ports and is designed to accept up to 3 MSATA devices in RAID1/0 (marketed as up to 1500MB/s disk performance).

This uses the usual Intel soft/chipset RAID with the C220 chipset (I believe this is referred to as RST).

Intel RST is supported by the mdraid driver under Linux.  This is the only solution I've found whereby Windows and Linux can agree on RAID.

I did hack the os-prober script as advised above when I installed F32 on this machine, however I came up with a better solution after dealing with F34 upgrade.

Since I've got 1 HDD for Linux, I just copied the Microsoft and MSI directories from the RAID EFI filesystem over to the EFI filesystem on the HDD, os-prober finds these EFI boot loaders just fine and Windows boots without any problem.

If you have the option of storing the EFI bootloader files on a conventional device, that is the preferred solution until a solution can be added to os-prober for Intel RST.

Comment: I contemplated doing the same thing when I was troubleshooting I personally just felt better about leaving the EFI bootloader files on the raid drive on the off chance that windows had to update them for some reason. Knowing me I'd forget to copy the new ones. odds of that happening are slim anyway. I'm glad it worked for you too.